# How to fix the Code::Blocks wizard to look for GTK+ 3.0 and not 2.0?

Tags: c, codeblocks, gtk3

I have been using Code::Blocks since I started programming in C, after trying every C compiler
in existence under windows I found Code::Blocks the most easiest to work with because I wouldn't have to spend an entire year learning how to use the program before I could start writing 'hello world' apps in it XD......

Anyway I installed GTK+ 3.0 and setup the environmental variables and ran the cmd prompt commands as the setup tutorial told me to.... I even ran the gtk-demo file from the cmd prompt....When I went to run through the Code::Blocks 13.10 gtk+ wizard it kept telling me that GTK+ seemed to be installed but that it couldn't find gtk.h after doing some digging I realized it was looking for the gtk-2.0 folder and not the gtk-3.0 folder...

Someone on another forum seemed to have gotten past that part by changing the 2.0's to 3.0's in the wizard script but claimed it gave him more errors once he would try to compile it.

Answer (score 6):

Alright people, I figured it out.....I went to command console and ran this command to get all the versions info: pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0

By doing that I got the following information: -mms-bitfields -IC:/GTK3/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/GTK3/include/cairo -IC:/GTK3/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/GTK3/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/GTK3/include/cairo -IC:/GTK3/include/pixman-1 -IC:/GTK3/include -IC:/GTK3/include/freetype2 -IC:/GTK3/include -IC:/GTK3/include/libpng15 -IC:/GTK3/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/GTK3/include/libpng15 -IC:/GTK3/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/GTK3/lib/glib-2.0/include

I went into Code::Blocks and I went to File->New->Project: I then right clicked the GTK+ project icon and selected 'edit this script' I went through the file and changed the files to match the versions in the above information

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // GTK project wizard
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // globals
    GtkPathDefault    <- _T("$(#gtk)");
    GtkPathDefaultInc <- _T("$(#gtk.include)");
    GtkPathDefaultLib <- _T("$(#gtk.lib)");
    GtkPath <- _T("");
    // GtkVersion <- 1; // 0 - GTK+, 1 - GTK+-2.0

    function BeginWizard()
    {
        local intro_msg = _T("Welcome to the new GTK project wizard!\n" +
                             "This wizard will guide you to create a new GTK project\n" +
                             "using the GTK cross-platform GUI toolkit\n\n" +
                             "When you're ready to proceed, please click \"Next\"...");

        local gtkpath_msg = _T("Please select the location of GTK on your computer.\n" +
                               "This is the top-level folder where GTK was installed.\n" +
                               "To help you, this folder must contain the subfolders\n" +
                               "\"include\" and \"lib\".");

        Wizard.AddInfoPage(_T("GtkIntro"), intro_msg);
        Wizard.AddProjectPathPage();
        if (PLATFORM == PLATFORM_MSW)
        {
            Wizard.AddGenericSelectPathPage(_T("GtkPath"), gtkpath_msg, _T("GTK's location:"),         GtkPathDefault);
        }
        /*else
        {
            Wizard.AddGenericSingleChoiceListPage(_T("GtkVersionPage"), _T("Please select the         GTK+ version you want to use."), _T("GTK+ 1.x;GTK+ 2.x"), GtkVersion); // select GTK+         version
        }*/
        Wizard.AddCompilerPage(_T(""), _T("gcc*"), true, true);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Gtk's path page
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function OnLeave_GtkPath(fwd)
    {
        if (fwd)
        {
            local dir         = Wizard.GetTextControlValue(_T("txtFolder")); // txtFolder is         the text control in GenericSelectPathPage
            local dir_nomacro = VerifyDirectory(dir);

            if (dir_nomacro.IsEmpty())
                return false;

            // verify include dependencies
            local dir_nomacro_inc = GetCompilerIncludeDir(dir, GtkPathDefault,         GtkPathDefaultInc);
            if (dir_nomacro_inc.IsEmpty())
                return false;
            if (!VerifyFile(dir_nomacro_inc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gtk-3.0") + wxFILE_SEP_PATH         +_T("gtk"), _T("gtk.h"), _T("GTK's include")))
                return false;

            // verify library dependencies
            local dir_nomacro_lib = GetCompilerLibDir(dir, GtkPathDefault, GtkPathDefaultLib);
            if (dir_nomacro_lib.IsEmpty())
                return false;
            if (!VerifyLibFile(dir_nomacro_lib, _T("gtk-win32-3.0"), _T("GTK's")))
                return false;


            GtkPath = dir; // Remember the original selection.

            local is_macro = _T("");

            // try to resolve the include directory as macro
            is_macro = GetCompilerIncludeMacro(dir, GtkPathDefault, GtkPathDefaultInc);
            if (is_macro.IsEmpty())
            {
                // not possible -> use the real inc path we had computed instead
                GtkPathDefaultInc = dir_nomacro_inc;
            }

            // try to resolve the library directory as macro
            is_macro = GetCompilerLibMacro(dir, GtkPathDefault, GtkPathDefaultLib);
            if (is_macro.IsEmpty())
            {
                // not possible -> use the real lib path we had computed instead
                GtkPathDefaultLib = dir_nomacro_lib;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Gtk's version page (For *nix users)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function OnLeave_GtkVersionPage(fwd)
    {
        if (fwd)
        {
            GtkVersion = Wizard.GetListboxSelection(_T("GenericChoiceList"));
        }
        return true;
    }

    // return the files this project contains
    function GetFilesDir()
    {
        return _T("gtk/files");
    }

    // setup the already created project
    function SetupProject(project)
    {
        if (PLATFORM == PLATFORM_MSW)
        {
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc);
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gtk-3.0"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("cairo"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gdk"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("glib-2.0"));
            // Notice GtkPathDefault*Lib* at some positions. This is correct as of 2.8.20
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultLib + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("glib-2.0") +         wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("include"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("pango-1.0"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultLib + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gtk-3.0")  +         wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("include"));
            project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("atk-1.0"));
            if ( IO.DirectoryExists(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gdk-pixbuf-2.0"))         )
                project.AddIncludeDir(GtkPathDefaultInc + wxFILE_SEP_PATH + _T("gdk-pixbuf-        2.0"));

            project.AddLibDir(GtkPathDefaultLib);

            // add link libraries
            project.AddLinkLib(_T("gtk-win32-3.0"));
            project.AddLinkLib(_T("gobject-2.0"));
            project.AddLinkLib(_T("glib-2.0"));

            // Notice: there are more libs required as the app gets more complex, e.g.:
            // pangocairo-1.0.lib, pangocairo-1.0.lib, libatk-1.0.dll.a,
            // gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib, gdk-win32-2.0.lib,  pango-1.0.lib,
            // gmodule-2.0.lib,    gthread-2.0.lib,    cairo.lib,
            // pangoft2-1.0.lib    (...)

            project.AddCompilerOption(_T("-mms-bitfields"));
        }
        else
        {
            /*if (GtkVersion == 1)
            {*/
            project.AddCompilerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags`"));
            project.AddLinkerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs`"));
            /*}
            else
            {
                project.AddCompilerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+ --cflags`"));
                project.AddLinkerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+ --libs`"));
            }*/
        }

        // enable compiler warnings (project-wide)
        WarningsOn(project, Wizard.GetCompilerID());

        // Debug
        local target = project.GetBuildTarget(Wizard.GetDebugName());
        if (!IsNull(target))
        {
            target.SetTargetType(ttConsoleOnly); // ttConsoleOnly: console for debugging
            target.SetOutputFilename(Wizard.GetDebugOutputDir() + Wizard.GetProjectName() +         DOT_EXT_EXECUTABLE);
            // enable generation of debugging symbols for target
            DebugSymbolsOn(target, Wizard.GetCompilerID());
        }

        // Release
        target = project.GetBuildTarget(Wizard.GetReleaseName());
        if (!IsNull(target))
        {
            target.SetTargetType(ttExecutable); // ttExecutable: no console
            target.SetOutputFilename(Wizard.GetReleaseOutputDir() + Wizard.GetProjectName() +         DOT_EXT_EXECUTABLE);
            // enable optimizations for target
            OptimizationsOn(target, Wizard.GetCompilerID());
        }

        return true;
    }
```

If you want to setup Code::Blocks so that it doesn't open a win32 console window behind your GTK+ GUI goto Project->Properties->Build targets  and then under "Selected build target options" select the Type: dropdown list and select GUI application, it will probably have Console Application selected

Edit: Come to find out, upon inspection of the script above I realized the you don't have to go through all that trouble to remove the console, all you need to do is select the dropdown menu to the right of 'run' on the toolbar and switch it from Debug to Release XD

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

THESE DETAILS MAY NOT APPLY TO ANY VERSION OF CODE::BLOCKS OTHER THAN 17.12

I had the same problem with Code::Blocks 17.12 on Ubuntu 16.04

As per the answer above, the solution (for me) was to modify the GTK Wizard script, but this is a little different than described, perhaps because of differing Code::Blocks versions.

Code::Blocks -> New -> Project -> right-click 'GTK+ Project' -> select 'Edit this script'

Code::Blocks will now display a script in an editor pane. But this script is locked. It also is not saved anywhere.

Save the file
Code::Blocks -> File -> Save

The file will be saved to ~/.local/share/codeblocks/templates/wizard/gtk as wizard.script

Close this file in Code::Blocks (click the 'x' in the editor pane tab)

Open the file using some other editor (vi(m), Geany, whatever...)

Near the base of the file are the lines...

```
    project.AddCompilerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags`"));

    project.AddLinkerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`"));
```

Either comment these out and add two new lines or modify the lines as follows

```
    project.AddCompilerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags`"));

    project.AddLinkerOption(_T("`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs`"));
```

Note 'gtk+-2.0' has been altered to 'gtk+-3.0' in both lines

Start Code::Blocks and create a NEW project. This should now compile.

Note: GTK3 projects created previously will NOT compile.

Note: The Code::Blocks New -> Project -> GTK+ Wizard icon will now display in RED. This indicates that the GTK+ project wizard script has been modified.