# Codecblocks: Cairo link

Tags: c, compilation, gtk, codeblocks, cairo

I'm trying to run a C program using Gtk3.0 and Cairo on a Codeblocks project.

But whenever I try to compile-run it, the codeblocks terminal emulator says:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/gobject/gsignal.c:2462: signal 'draw' is invalid for instance '0x211a870' of type 'GtkDrawingArea'
```

The line it refers to is this one:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(actarea), "draw"   , G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);
```

The Gtk window actually appears but NOT Cairos drawing area.

This is odd, because I compiled it manually (with emacs) and used

```
gcc -o p1 p1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

and did work! Same code in a codeblocks and that message appears on codeblocks terminal emulator.
I need to use codeblocks but this keep me from running my program.

I already tried to include in "Compiler>other options" the commands

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo`
`pkg-config --libs cairo`
```

but didn't work.

What is happening and how to overcome this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What options you had configured in CB originally, before you tried the `cairo` stuff.

Comment: I've always used emacs. This is my first time using codeblocks, so besides that change i've made to compiler>"other options" codeblocks is with its default configurations, I believe

Comment: Your Code::Blocks project must be linking against GTK+ 2. You will need to either fix your project or change your code, as the drawing models changed entirely between GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3.

Comment: @andlabs could you help me on how to fix my project to solve this problem? From what I get from you I need to link my project to GTK+3. I'm not that experienced in programming or IDE's and would be helpful if you could teach me how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use Code::Blocks; sorry. Perhaps someone else will know...

Comment: Thanks a lot, @andlabs! I configured codeblocks script project and worked! Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339805/how-to-fix-the-codeblocks-wizard-to-look-for-gtk-3-0-and-not-2-0

Comment: since the 'working' method uses `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`, why are you setting the `compiler-other` options to `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo` and `pkg-config --libs cairo` when what is needed is: `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an **override** method, the implementation of this method **must exist** at compile time.